# Sample web application with XSS vulnerabilities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I want to do 2 things:

1. Demonstrate xss vulnerabilities to my colleagues and show how to fix
   them
2. Check some tools if they can detect vulnerarbilities

For this I need a sample web application preferable in ASP.NET MVC with most common vulnerabilies. Does such a sample site already exist?

Comment: You can use this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512662.aspx) from Microsoft.but I think you should search in google and get many result

Comment: Realy a nice article, but I need the sample app.

Comment: I think if you understand what is XSS you can write simple application

Comment: No because I am to lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CodeProject article + example application:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102284/SQL-Injection-and-Cross-Site-Scripting

Answer (score 0):

> Demonstrate xss vulnerabilities to my colleagues and show how to fix
>   them

Try this: http://google-gruyere.appspot.com

I used it to demonstrate xss vulnerabilities to my colleagues. ;)

> Check some tools if they can detect vulnerarbilities

Try manually. After introducing Google Gruyere to my colleagues, we found a XSS vulnerability into our application in 5 minutes...